# How to separate a face at one edge only?

Tags: edit-mode, edges

Is it possible to separate faces only at one edge? My goal isn't to separate the edge entirely from the object but rather just to create a small crease in an object by moving edges from the main body (thus creating a hole). I've googled a lot and only found how to entirely split an edge, making it independent from the main body and it's not what I'm trying to do. Any advice on how I could approach this?

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please don't write in all caps in the title or body of any posts, it is the written equivalent of shouting, is [harder to read](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_caps#Readability) and may be [considered rude](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_caps#Computing). Please use the [edit] button below the post to change you text into regular case.

Comment: See Lukas' answer and my comment there for the solution. Just note that the new quad faces on the border like the one on the left which is half-shaded in your sketch now is a non-planar face. You should probably select the top left and bottom right vertices and press J to split the face in two tris, and the same for the one on the other side.

Comment: There is a problem in your question: your drawing shows the faces split by more than one edge… ALT + M, and choose an option. You want to split by vertices. Keep in mind, splitting a single edge is impossible in a manifold mesh, because the edge shares vertices with other edges… Ah OK, you want a hole only on top and to add 2 faces on sides…

Answer (score 5):

I think what you are looking for is called **Rip Vertices**.

In edit mode, while selecting an edge, press <kbd>V</kbd> to rip the edge from the mesh to create a hole. If you'd like to fill the created hole, use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> instead.

[image: GIF showing how to create a vent with rip vertices.]

Notice where the mouse is before ripping. The mouse's location will determine how the vertices are ripped from their nearby geometry.

See the [Blender Docs](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/vertex/rip_vertices.html) for more info.

Comment: **Alt+V** is _Rip Vertices and Fill_ which keeps the new and old vertices connected with faces. To get a hole just use _Rip Vertices_ (as you mention) which is **V**.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann Actually, If I'm getting OP right, they want **V** > (drop) > **Alt-V** (with constraint) > **M** merge by distance.. leaving a vent with triangular sides and a hole at the top? I wonder if there's  a snappier way..

Comment: @RobinBetts Maybe, I'm actually not sure what exactly is wanted. That's why I added the two different methods, V and Alt+V (and just to make clear that _Rip Vertices_ and _Rip Vertices and Fill_ are two different tools), since the tool name and manual link to V is given, but the shortcut in the answer is Alt+V.

Comment: @Gordon Yup, I seem to have to use both. .. haven't found a way in one move ..

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: This is exactly what I've been looking for! Thank you so much! Did not know about Rip Vertices.

Answer (score 3):

This is How I would do it: just extrude the faces, edge slide the bottom back to the original surface and delete the faces where you need the holes…
<kbd>E</kbd>; <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>G</kbd>; <kbd>X</kbd> to extrude, slide, delete…

[image]

If you don't have automerge enabled, <kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>M</kbd>, <kbd>B</kbd> to select everything and merge by distance (remove doubles).